# Loading scripts on a single page plants the script in the footer

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using this code to plant a script on a spesific page, it works but inserts the script into the bottom of the page not the top - I'm at a loss to explain why! Is there a way to do this that results in the script being inserted inside the head tags.

```
function single_page_load() {
    if ( !is_page_template( 'interactive-map.php' ) )
    return;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'map', get_template_directory_uri() . 'jquery-map/map.js', array('jquery'), '1.4.2', true );
    }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'single_page_load' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script` accepts 5 parameters. The fifth one is `$in_footer`. If that parameter is set to true the script will load in the footer.

If it is set to false it will load in the head, **unless** a dependency (like jQuery in your code) is set to show up in the footer.